# Construction of DSL from existing Meta-model

Tags: dsl, xtext, metamodel, mda

i want to create my own DSL, i already have a meta model and i want to know if there is any tutorial or any thing that can help me to create my own DSL from my meta model.
ps: i'm planning to use Xtext framework to implement my DSL

Comment: What exactly do you expect? Did you have a look at the Xtext project from existing metamodel wizard?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich actually not yet , well i'm not familiar with DSLs at all , and i just started reading about it and now i'm required to create an 'abstract syntax' and 'concrete syntax'  . for the 'abstract syntax' i'm guessing that i should implement my meta model in eclipse with EMF , but i have no idea about how to implement the 'concrete syntax'  ( for now i just need to propose a DSML i dont need to implement it with XText yet )

Comment: How far ist the syntax between the existing metamodel and the concrete syntax you have in mind

Comment: well you are talking to to someone who has a very little bit of knowledge about this task , so my problem is that i don't know how to start , but here is what i have in my mind , i have a meta model , and i need to generate 'abstract syntax' and 'concrete syntax' ,  the vocabulary must be inspired from the meta model ( i read in an article that meta model must drive my implementation of the DSL)

Comment: Well hard to help you then. It basically works and just give it a try. A quick shot should be doable in a few hours

Comment: i wish if i find just an example of meta model and related DSL just to have an idea about how things work any way thank you sir for your answers

Comment: Is your problem the Xtext part or the metamodel part. If it is the Xtext part you should get in touch with a derives metamodel and the grammar language first and then switch to an external metamodel . But that highly depends on your metamodel, it’s quality, it’s size etc.

Comment: There is no big difference between a grammar for an existing metamodel and one that is derived. And all other Xtext parts are the same. So can you be a bit more concrete with your concerns / missing knowledge

Comment: And what about creating a new simple metamodel and then a grammar for it

Comment: my problem is not XText , before i get into XText i need to propose f concrete syntax if my supervisor agree with it than i ll try to implement it with XText , i don't know even how it looks like ( i just found a tool 'EMFText' i think it generates automatically  the concrete syntax )

Comment: As I said Xtext does it too. But you should really Rakete time and come up with something yourself